# Catch a JSON array into a MVC3 controller action

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an javascript array like this:

```
var optionArray = new Array();
optionArray["totalBankAmount"] = $("#totalBankAmountID").val();
optionArray["singlePlayerAmount"] = $("#singlePlayerAmountID").val();
..... (more array data)
```

I am sending this Array like this into StartOption (a MVC3 Controller):

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/StartOption/Index/",
        data: { allOptions: JSON.stringify(optionArray) },
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        timeout: 10000,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            ....
        }
});
```

How Index Action will catch that optionArray ? how i get those data by there array index name into my Index action ?

Please give me a good example, I am new in MVC3.

and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have an javascript array like this:

No, you don't have an array. Arrays in javascript must have zero based integer indexes. What you have is a javascript object.

So there are 2 scenarios:

- You want to work with objects
- You want to work with arrays

Let's cover the objects scenario first. So you have an object:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    public string Baz { get; set; }
}
```

and then you want to pass it to a controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Foo foo)
{
    ...
}
```

here's how the calling code might look like:

```
var foo = {};
foo['bar'] = 'some bar';
foo['baz'] = 'some baz';

// or the equivalent:
// var foo = {};
// foo.bar = 'some bar';
// foo.baz = 'some baz';

// or the equivalent:
// var foo = { bar: 'some bar', baz: 'some baz' };

$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("index", "startoption")',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ foo: foo }),
    type: 'POST',
    timeout: 10000,
    success: function (result) {
        ....
    }
});
```

---

And the second case, with arrays:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Foo[] foos)
{
    ...
}
```

and the calling code:

```
var foos = [];

var foo1 = {};
foo1['bar'] = 'some bar 1';
foo1['baz'] = 'some baz 1';
foos.push(foo1);

var foo2 = {};
foo2['bar'] = 'some bar 2';
foo2['baz'] = 'some baz 2';
foos.push(foo2);

// or the equivalent:
// var foos = [ { bar: 'some bar 1', baz: 'some baz 1' }, 
//              { bar: 'some bar 2', baz: 'some baz 2' } ];

$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("index", "startoption")',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ foos: foos }),
    type: 'POST',
    timeout: 10000,
    success: function (result) {
        ....
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.sorry for my wrong information. I want to work with objects array and here you set two object in that javascript object array and two properties in Foo class but in my option i don't know how many objects will pass into that Index ActionResult. So what should i do that time ?

Comment: Write a loop and append objects dynamically using the `.push` method I illustrated.

Comment: So what will be that look of that Foo class property ?

Comment: The Foo class properties will contain the information you need to pass from the client. I have no idea what information you want to pass. If you want to pass simple values you use scalar properties, if you want to pass collections, you use arrays, etc...

Comment: I am sorry my english is not good enough to make you understand. i got it. Thank you for your help :)