# script for window.location.href error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, redirect

this Q. is a continue of this question [first qestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41441305/passing-dataid-with-redircettoaction-to-url-using-viewmodel?noredirect=1#comment70093767_41441305) I have a form that I need to redirect to action with the form uploaded details (just like In stackoverflow) , but apparently because i'm using Ajax , it prevent it from redirect , I have tried to add my Ajax a redirect but I keep getting error and wrong Url . it should redirect from http://localhost:1914/En/VoosUp/Create To http://localhost:1914/En/events/Index/42 (E.G. Id number) the results i'm getting with what I wrote are in my Js Code 
How can I redirect it to the correct url  (Events/Index/Id )
Thanks in advance 
Js

```
function GetLocation() {
    var geocoder = new window.google.maps.Geocoder();

    var street = document.getElementById('txtAddress').value;
    var city = document.getElementById('txtCity').value;
    var address = city + street;
    console.log(address);
    var labelLat = document.getElementById('Latitude');
    var labellong = document.getElementById('longitude');

    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address },
        function(results, status) {
            if (status == window.google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                console.log("Latitude: " + latitude + "\nLongitude: " + longitude); //Ok.

                labelLat.value = latitude; //Ok.
                labellong.value = longitude;
                var form = $('#RestoForm')[0];
                var formData = new FormData(form);
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'Create',
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    data: formData,
                    datatype: "html",
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#RestoForm').html(data),
                            //   window.location.href = '@Url.Content:("~/Events/Index")' + "Id";
                            //= A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).
                            // En/VoosUp/@Url.Content:("~/Events/Index")Id
                            window.location.href = '@Url.Action("~/Events/Index")';
                        // =The resource cannot be found >
                        //En/VoosUp/@Url.Action("Events/Index 

                    }

                });

                error: function e(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
                }
            }
        });
};`
```

Controller:

```
 [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var viewModel = new LectureFormViewModel
        {
            Genres = _context.Genres.ToList(),

        };
        return View("Gigform", viewModel);
    }

    [Authorize, HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(LectureFormViewModel viewModel)
    {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            viewModel.Genres = _context.Genres.ToList();

            return View("Gigform", viewModel);
        }


        var lectureGig = new LectureGig
        {
           //Parameters
        };

        _context.LectureGigs.Add(lectureGig);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        // return this.RedirectToAction( "events", (c=>c.Index(lectureGig.Id));
        return RedirectToAction("index", "Events", new { id = lectureGig.Id });
    }
```

and the target

```
 public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        var lecturegig = _context.LectureGigs.Include(g => g.Artist)
           .Include(g => g.Genre)
           .SingleOrDefault(g => g.Id == id);
        if (lecturegig == null)
            return HttpNotFound();
        var viewmodel = new GigDetailViewModel { LectureGig = lecturegig };

        return View("index", viewmodel);
    }
```

Comment: `'@Url.Action("Index", "Events")';`

Comment: @Satpal http://localhost:1914/En/VoosUp/@Url.Action(%22Index%22,%20%22Events%22) >   window.location.href= '@Url.Action("Index", "Events")'; also not working for me

Comment: try this - window.location.href= @String.Concat("'", Url.Action("Index", "Events"), "'");

Comment: @majita its missing a quoted somewhere &I cant find where >Url is not defined

Comment: just a silly question: Ajax is designed to avoid redirecting. What you want to do can be done with a simple form submission. Why do you need to simulate the plain form submission (post with Ajax and then redirect)?

Comment: @LelioFaieta Its because  need to add the Lat / Long to my Db.

Comment: this can be done without ajax

Comment: @LelioFaieta it could be interesting can you show me how ?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it if your JavaScript is in the cshtml:

```
   var id = 1;
   var url = '@Url.Action("Index", "Events")';
   window.location.href = url + "/" + id;
```

Based on your description however it seems that you are trying to call this from a .js file which has no idea about MVC helpers so instead you can try something like this:

```
var id = 1; 

var getUrl = window.location;
var baseUrl = getUrl.protocol + "//" + getUrl.host + "/" + getUrl.pathname.split('/')[1];

window.location.href = baseUrl + '/Events/Index' + id;
```

To get the correct Id modify your action to return the Id e.g.

```
public JsonResult Create(LectureFormViewModel viewModel)
{
   return Json(new { Id=lectureGig.Id });
}
```

then you can access this Id in JavaScript e.g.

```
 success: function(data) {
   var id = data.Id;
 }
```

Comment: this bring me to http://localhost:1914/En/VoosUp/@Url.Action(%22Index%22,%20%22Events%22)/1 & request Url is (its a 404) /En/VoosUp/@Url.Action("Index", "Events")/1

Comment: @AssafOur have edited my answer to cater for .js file

Comment: we are getting there , I wasn't sure how to use the json so I have use the option ofhaving the script on Chtml file, the url I get not has no index and the Id is still static (1)now it look like :http://localhost:1914/En/Events/1

Comment: @AssafOur You need to get the Id back from the server i.e. from your Controllers Create action. There are various ways to do this but here is an example using json - http://stackoverflow.com/a/11267280/2401021 you need to change the datatype of your ajax request from html to json for this to work

Answer (score 0):

If it is in a cshtml file you can use the code

```
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Events")'+ "?id=1";
```

If you are in js file

```
window.location.href='/Events/Index?id=1'
```

Comment: window.location.href='/Events/Index?id=1' in the Js file is getting me to http://localhost:1914/Events/Index?id=1 (Please note the globalizing (En) is missing , plus the id is static 1 ,and not the new Id .Should  be ../En/Envets/Index/1 (the dynamic Id) .thnks